# Template URL greyed out in SharePoint 2013

Tags: template

[image]

Do you know why this could be?

Another question: Is it possible to save a template in a different library (not the nameofmylibrary/Forms) ?? And just enter the link to the document..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Its because Content types are enabled. Forgot about that!

Answer (score -1):

You can find and edit the template when you have created an custom content type. The template is located in .../Forms/[Name of your content type]/template.docx. Other template files are not in use anymore.

[image]